# error when use ant to build android project

Tags: android, ant

jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: csi.keystore. csi.keystore must ref
erence a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding pub
lic key certificate chain..

who has idea? thanks...

Comment: Did you modify your build script? If you did, can you post some code?

What IDE are you using? Typically the ant script gets generated if you use Eclipse or Netbeans.

I need some more information in order to help you with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your building in release mode. If you build in debug mode it should work. I need to set thus up for release mode myself so let me know how you do it in release mode if you get it working

Answer (score 0):

thanks Ben!

Yes,I build it in debug mode it should work.But I build it in release get error,I cannot find the reason for it.

```
        <!-- sign the APK -->
        <echo>Signing final apk...</echo>
        <signjar
                jar="${out-unsigned-package}"
                signedjar="${out-unaligned-package}"
                keystore="${key.store}"
                storepass="${key.store.password}"
                alias="${key.alias}"
                keypass="${key.alias.password}"/>
        <!-- zip align the APK -->
        <echo>Running zip align on final apk...</echo>
        <exec executable="${zipalign}" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-f" />
            <arg value="4" />
            <arg path="${out-unaligned-package}" />
            <arg path="${out-release-package}" />
        </exec>
        <echo>Release Package: ${out-release-package}</echo>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem.
The cause was that **I was specifying a different keystore than the one for which I was providing the credentials.**
Make sure that the following properties (if you've defined them) match:

- key.store
- key.store.password
- key.alias
- key.alias.password

In my case, I has specified the first two in my local.properties file (that I had copied from another project assuming it only held the SDK dir) and the last two specified the correct credentials.

Hope this helps.